# AngularJS has httpInterceptors, but they don't detect/react to a socket connection loss

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, sockets

I am working on an Angular application using Cordova, which was not timing out either due to a non-responsive http service (no connection loss but no response), or after a socket-level disconnection.  Adding a simple httpInterceptor which sets a timeout solved the problem with the non-responsive server, but the application will still neither timeout nor detect a connection loss, if the request has been sent and then the socket connection is lost.

An easy way to test this is: on Ripple, with a connection manager like TCPViewer open, trigger the http client call to the server, then forcibly disconnect the TCP connection (port 80).  On a device like iOS or Android, turn on airplane mode after making the request.

The application will wait indefinitely for a response, and has to be shutdown and restarted.

Does anyone know of a way to trap this connection loss event?  The specific interceptor code being used is as follows:

```
      .factory('timeoutInterceptor', ['$q', '$timeout', function ($q, $timeout) {
          return {
              request: function (config) {
                  config.timeout = $timeout(function () { config.timedOut = true }, 30000);
                  return config;
              },
              responseError: function (rejection) {
                  return $q.reject(rejection);
              }
          };
```

Thanks.